# Fill pandas dataframe cells with specific values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas.dataframe column, where my first four values should be filled into other cells upto 200 lines below in the same order in the same column. I can do it via loop (for) but it does not fit for purpose, since i will do lots of this loops and will take significant CPU time. I am looking for something much more efficient (may be like *append* or *concat*?). Hope my question is clear!

This is my input:

```
index y
0  0
1  5 
2  5
3  0
4  NaN
5  NaN
6  NaN
7  NaN
8  NaN
...
1456  NaN
```

This is what i want to get:

```
index y
0  0
1  5 
2  5
3  0
4  0
5  5
6  5
7  0
8  0
...
1456  NaN
```

Thank You for help!

P.S. Thanks for comments on updating question!!!

Comment: Hey I can see you are new here. Welcome!! You should read this before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. More precisely: How about providing some sample data and expected output?

Comment: update the question with sample datas'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say we create your `DataFrame` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
patern = [0,5,5,0]
df = pd.DataFrame(patern + [np.nan]*1453)
```

Your `DataFrame` would then be:

```
>>> df
        0
0     0.0
1     5.0
2     5.0
3     0.0
4     NaN
5     NaN
...   ...
1452  NaN
1453  NaN
1454  NaN
1455  NaN
1456  NaN

[1457 rows x 1 columns]
```

You can then fill the `DataFrame` with the `patern` up to line 200 with below code using `fillna` function:

```
df_out = df.fillna(pd.DataFrame(patern*(200/len(patern))))
```

Then your output `DataFrame` would be like:

```
>>> df_out
        0
0     0.0
1     5.0
2     5.0
3     0.0
4     0.0
5     5.0
6     5.0
7     0.0
8     0.0
9     5.0
10    5.0
...   ...
1452  NaN
1453  NaN
1454  NaN
1455  NaN
1456  NaN

[1457 rows x 1 columns]
```

Where the following elements determine the limit you want:

```
>>> df_out.loc[199]
0    0.0
Name: 199, dtype: float64
>>> df_out.loc[200]
0   NaN
Name: 200, dtype: float64
```